# how to show alert dialog from non-UI class ? getting error like -Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

getting error like -java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I am cerating application which has many activities . If user doesn't respond for a specific time (15 mins) then after 15 mins I wnat to show a dialog box which ask user "Are you still there ?"  and if user press "NO" application should close.
I tried to do this with the help of 
[Application idle time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075180/application-idle-time)

but I didn't created ControlApplication.java
I directly called touch() from my each activity.
and called Waiter class constructor from another java file which is global for my application.
here is my code
Waiter.java

```
public class Waiter extends Thread
{
private static final String TAG=Waiter.class.getName();
private long lastUsed;
private long period;
private boolean stop;
private Context killContext;

public Waiter( long period, Context context )
{
    this.period=period;
    stop=false;
    killContext = context;
}

public void run()
{
    long idle=0;
    this.touch();
    do
    {
        idle=System.currentTimeMillis()-lastUsed;
        Log.d(TAG, "Application is idle for -------------------------------------->"+idle +" ms");
        Log.d(TAG, "lastUsed is  -------------------------------------->"+lastUsed +" ms");
        Log.d(TAG, "currentTimeMillis is  -------------------------------------->"+System.currentTimeMillis() +" ms");
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000); //check every 50 seconds
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "----------------Waiter interrupted!-----------------------------------");
        }
        if(idle > period)
        {
            idle=0;
            Log.d(TAG, "----------------inside if-----------------------------------");
            AlertDialog.Builder killBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( killContext );                    
            killBuilder.setMessage("Are you still there ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            android.os.Process.killProcess(
                                android.os.Process.myPid() );
                        }
                    });
            Log.d(TAG, "----------------inside if killBuilder.create();;-----------------------------------");
            AlertDialog alert = killBuilder.create();
             Log.d(TAG, "----------------inside if alert.show();-----------------------------------");
            alert.show();
        }
    }
    while(!stop);
    Log.d(TAG, "--------------------------------Finishing Waiter thread-----------------------------");
}

public synchronized void touch()
{
    lastUsed=System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public synchronized void forceInterrupt()
{
    this.interrupt();
}

public synchronized void setPeriod(long period)
{
    this.period=period;
}
```

}

but  at alert.show(); I am getting above error. please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying Updating the UI from a non-UI thread, you should update the UI from the UI thread only else you have to use a `Handler` or `runOnUiThread()`.

Try this,

```
killContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`AlertDialog` can't be shown in any context, except current activity. So you have to be sure that `killContext` extends `Activity` class and it is on screen write now.

Answer (score 0):

- best way to do it is `AsyncTask` .
- short way is call  R`unOnUiThread( new runnable)` and write alert dialog related thing inside runnable .
- alternative way `Handler` class implementation

Comment: I would like to go with short way but where should I write RunOnUiThread( new runnable) exactly ? I am extremely new to this so please explain it in detail.

Comment: to being new is not unfair, but ask for help even if you can do it by refer docs and study actually is .

Answer (score 0):

You should store an Activity instead of a Context in the `killContext` field, then you can call `runOnUiThread`:

```
killActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){public void run(){alert.show();}})
```

Comment: how should I get the activity and store it in killContext ?

Answer (score 0):

I have also observed that if a process is put on non-ui thread and it raises alert without runOnUiThread, it causes some kind of hang and android ui thread goes in ANR... Anybody has this same observation ?