# Android : Exit the application after certain interval of time if its in background

Tags: android

I want to close my application after certain interval of time it its in background. I found many examples to close the application in background and about how to know if application is in background but i didn't find anything related to this.

I want to implement something like auto Logout feature like session, if there is no interaction with application then after specific time of interval is should closed.

Any idea and suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about application idle, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075857/1039411). There you should find something useful.