# Blur (Hide) content of app when it goes to the recents

Tags: android

In application I need to Blur content when it goes to the 'recents' and also to make screenshot when user work with the app (this is optional, but high needed feature).
I see a few questions ([question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770921/how-to-hide-last-activity-view-in-android-recent-list-using-a-locker-screen-imp), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642642/hide-screen-in-recent-apps-list-but-allow-screenshots) ) and answers about this - but none of them are work!

But users dont't bring me - one of them send my screenshot from his phone (Oneplus with Android 13) - when all secure apps hide its content with this screen and blur screenshot of app -

[image]

Does anyone know - what is it? Can it be some system GUI part of Oneplus? Or maybe at this moment there is some lib, that CAN hide content? Or maybe something else?

Also Same apps on another devices with same Android OS version doesn't hide content.

**So, I have 2 questions -**

1. How to not only hide (with white screen as default), but also BLUR content when the app goes to the recents?
2. Can solution on screenshot be specific part of phone GUI?

Comment: Have you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android

Comment: "I see a few questions... but none of them are work!" -- `FLAG_SECURE` generally works. However, since you did not provide a [mcve], we cannot help you debug your use of `FLAG_SECURE`. It is also possible that OnePlus make some mistake that broke `FLAG_SECURE`, though this is unlikely.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've forgot the main part of my question - I need not just hide but BLUR content also. And at this moment I didn't find any solution to do this

Comment: @SamirSpahic I've forgot the main part of my question - I need not just hide but BLUR content also. And at this moment I didn't find any solution to do this. I've look your link - but it doesnt match my needs

Comment: "I need not just hide but BLUR content also" -- if you are hiding it, there is nothing to blur. "I didn't find any solution to do this" -- that is because there is no option for that.

Comment: @CommonsWare by default SECURE flag show just white screen for the app. But I need to show blured content of app, not just white. Many applications do smth like this with their apps