# How to find out idle application in android?

Tags: android, mobile, adb, monkeyrunner

We are trying to automate the testing of android phones. We want to run a benchmark application in android through monkeyrunner/adb, at the end of test how can i detect the test is complete or not through adb/monkeyrunner. Is there any command to check the application idle case in android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075180/application-idle-time. might help

Comment: We dont need an application side logic. Because the application source is not ours.

Comment: You should find another way of determining if tests are finished, but if you can't `top` may be a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you going to do after you determined that the benchmark run has finished? Probably parse the logcat output for the benchmark results. So why won't you just monitor the logcat anyway and finding the results would mean that the benchmark run has finished.

In case your benchmark app of choice (which you did not mention for some reason) does not log the results - just monitor the facility you were going to use to collect the results.