# Reduce idle timeout after locking the screen

Tags: android

I want to test a application in idle mode. So to do that i need to wait for the device to get into idle mode which is taking 20 mins in my android device. Here `idle mode` means after sometime of switching of the screen, the device will get it into one mode where the cpu will goes off and the network will be disabled for the applications as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isDeviceIdleMode()). So anybody help me to know is there any way to reduce the `idle timeout` using programmatic or any other way. I searched a lot. But i can't able to find anything.

When i search i found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17441576/3049065) which is related to idle mode of application. So it is not a duplicate question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If by sleep you're referring to the new doze system brought out in android 6, check out the following link which explains how you can send commands with adb to put the device into sleep mode.

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#testing_doze