# Session timed out and automatic logout from application after few hours in android

Tags: android, session

I am new to Android App development.I have a small issue.Working on my Android Application if hit on  **"Home"** Button the application  goes to background after some time again if  go to **"Home"** and click my app icon it again getting started from my `last viewed` `Activity`(screen). Till now its fine,instead of last viewed screen , here  i want to ***Logout automatically***  and it should show message like "**Your Session timed out So Please Login  again** " or  **redirect to Login page** " Then *check the credentials and Allow the user to continue the same application* . I am maintaining all the user credentials i.e email,username ,password and user id through out my application by using shared Preference.**How to achieve this automatic Logout from application after few hours if it is in background in android or  if the application is not used by the user or   remains inactive for some times??**

Waiting for Your suggestion   ??

Comment: Any Idea how to Use a static data member that represents the token and the time it was validated. Check the token in onResume() of each activity. If the token is missing or is out of date, redirect the user to the login activity... ??

Comment: you got the solution ?

Comment: Yes .. I got the way how to achive this requirement :)

Comment: @subha.. if  you got the way, then  share plz...

Answer (score 0):

use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) in android to automatically check the session in asynctask and give particular time in `millisecond` destory the  user Session  and show the timeout message in `Toast`.

Comment: I think u are not getting me.. If i set particular time if the user is using the application and time completed the application will logout.But my question is that if it is inactive or if the user is not using it than only after few times the user should logout

Comment: or else you have to handle it in webservice

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one its may help you.

1.this is one way:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

         if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
         {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(intent);  
          return true;
          }
 return false;
};
```

2.Another way: you can use **onStop()** method.It will invoked when the Home button is pressed.In that do your stuff.

Comment: I want to use logout automatically on in active  not onStop()

Comment: below code is really works for me please try and let me know.                                                                      @Override
 protected void onStop() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(intent);  
          finish();
  super.onStop();
 }

Comment: Please read my question and comment again .. I want to logout my activity when it is ideal not on stop. thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: Actually If i use your code it will finish the application on activity change every time. I don't want this.. i want if the application is ideal or in inactive state than only it should finish :(

Comment: Sorry..! it works when you have only one activity.can you refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075180/application-idle-time).

Comment: Yes but i am looking for full application