# Getting idle times of other applications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I am developing an app, where i want to list **idle time** of other applications installed on my android phone. I went through this SO question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075180/application-idle-time , but it will not list other application's idle time.

Comment: This works for your application, I'm not sure it is allowed to watch other application's idle time.

Comment: @shkschneider But clean master has listed all installed applications idle times like idle from 2 months, idle from 2 days etc...

Comment: I'm sorry I have no clue. Seems not possible (at least on non-rooted devices) from my searches.

Comment: @CommonsWare how to list idle time of other applications installed on my android phone?