# Unable to override touch and forceinterrupt methods in Xamarin Thread

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, background-thread

I have created android application in Eclipse java and which should be quit after 30mins if it is idle. I have used the following like for doing this.

[Application idle time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075180/application-idle-time)

I have tried the same in Xamarin Android, but it showing following error in touch and forceinterrupt methods,

[image: Error in Thread]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such keyword on .net at all. You have to use next:

```
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
//...
public void touch() 
{
    lock(syncLock) 
    { 
        /* code */ 
    }
}

public void forceInterrupt()
{
    lock(syncLock) 
    { 
        /* code */ 
    }
}
```