# Catch inactivity for X defined time in android

Tags: android, thread-safety

I am developing an application that will be running. In this application, if the user didn't do anything in the application within X minutes, the application will show a show a popup telling user about the inactivity of app. 
My question is, how can I code on detecting *IDLE within X minutes*?

Comment: use Activity.onUserInteraction

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are asking about an Activity being foregrounded and there is an inactivity for some time. Assuming the same here is the approach
1) In activity onresume start a timer and associate a timertask which shows a dialog (do not forget runonUIthread) 
2) override 'dispatchTouchEvent' and 'dispatchKeyEvent' and in it reset the timer

In activity onpause clean up the timer

Comment: Can you pls provide with working example. googling has pissed me off..:'(

Comment: I am taking help from [Android UI example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075180/application-idle-time) but it is throwing error :'(

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(707): java.lang.ClassCastException: 
E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.synchronoss.smartcare.android.twctechassist.app.MainActivity.onUserInteraction(MainActivity.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2094)
E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)